# iReport 5.6.0 jar list needed to use jaspers in a webapp

Tags: jar, jasper-reports, dependencies

I need the **complete** list of jars to use jasper reports designed with iReport 5.6.0 in my web app

Comment: start designing you will know it....

Comment: I already designed the report on iReport 5.1.0 and my app has all the libs to print the pdf.
Now I want to use iReport 5.6.0 but I don't remember the complete list of jar. for example itext, xml etc

Answer (score 0):

These are the minimum jars required to generated a report

```
1. commons-io.2.4.jar
2. jasperreports.5.1.0.jar
3. com.lowagie.itext.2.1.7.jar
```

Additional jars

```
1. groovy-all.2.4.0.jar
2. jasperreports-fonts.4.0.0.jar
```

Comment: this is incomplete, there ara also poi, xml api ecc...
I need the complete list

Comment: The above listed are the base jars you need to generate a report.

Comment: If in the report there are barcodes or other components I need other jar.
I would a complete list for all the possibilities